# How to access a multi dimensional array with a variable string?

Tags: ruby

Out of the following the last one does not work:

```
puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin][:jetty][:name]
puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin]['jetty'][:name]
puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin]["'#{entry}'"][:name]
```

What syntax do I need to follow in order to use a variable's value in the index when accessing a multi dimensional array?

UPDATE:
I think entry is a String but I could be wrong so here's the statement that sets it up for you the educated helper to determine what's what:

```
Dir.entries("/var/plugins/").any? do |entry|
    puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin][:jetty][:name]
    puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin]['jetty'][:name]
    puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin]["'#{entry}'"][:name]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hash is indexed with symbols, so you should convert your string into a symbol, with `entry.intern()`.

```
puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin][entry.intern][:name]
```

Edit: `to_sym` and `intern` are [aliases of the String class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_sym). So entry has to be a string, which it seems to be according to your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a key `String` in your hash, but it look like you have symoblized keys in hour hash. In this case, convert your string to `Symbol`, before you use it as a key.

Try this code:

```
puts node.elasticsearch[:plugin][entry.to_sym][:name]
```

Comment: sorry i didn't scroll down and ended up using the answer from @philant before i ever saw yours ...